# Inner join with data.tables vs. inner join in SQL with composite character key (encoding issue?)

Tags: sql, r, data.table

Maybe is a naive question, but given the following SQL query:

```
SELECT *
FROM DT1 
INNER JOIN DT2 
  ON (DT1.col1 = DT2.col1) 
  AND (DT1.col2 = DT2.col2) 
  AND (DT1.col3 = DT2.col3);
```

should it be equivalent with the following in R, or ?

```
DT1[DT2, nomatch=0]
```

where the keys were set like:

```
setkey(DT1, col1, col2, col3)
setkey(DT2, col1, col2, col3)
```

What can determine the fact that I get different results?

UPDATE:
As @jangorecki suggested there might be an issue of encoding.
Anyhow I'll try to provide the data. I am deeply sorry for the big data sets, but is hard to detect what can cause the issues and come up with a minimal example.

```
library(data.table)
# the files are in this repository: https://github.com/ValStef/ConsvStat
DT1 <-  fread("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/ValStef/ConsvStat/master/DT1.txt")
# on my PC I get no error with fread for DT1 but seems that when reading from github I get some errors (otherwise try to download the DT1.zip file from the repository)
DT2 <-  fread("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/ValStef/ConsvStat/master/DT2.txt")
# note that file DT1 is comma separated and the DT2 is tab separated (but fread should manage
# Initially I just neglected the encoding warnings

# set the key for each data table
setkey(DT1, country, region, habitatcode)
setkey(DT2, country, region, habitatcode)

# perform the join
DT.inner.join <- DT2[DT1, nomatch=0]
# it works, except that I get 3069 rows
```

-

```
# but running the SQL statement in the original MS Access mdb file returns 3117 rows 
# which is the number of rows of DT1, which is the expected result
SELECT DT1.country, DT1.region, DT1.habitatcode, DT2.habitatgroup
FROM DT1 
INNER JOIN DT2 
ON DT1.country = DT2.country
AND DT1.region = DT2.region
AND DT1.habitatcode = DT2.habitatcode
```

You can also find the SQL query result in the mentioned repository

```
SQL_output <-  fread("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/ValStef/ConsvStat/master/Query1.csv")
```

I tried to follow the suggestion from https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/issues/685 (join on character columns with different encodings). I run the functions proposed by @stefanfritsch setencoding() and setencodingv() like:

```
setencoding(DT1, country, region, habitatcode)
setencoding(DT2, country, region, habitatcode)
# after which I set the keys again and I run the join
```

But I get the same issue.

The merge() functions (as expected) will not bring any change:

```
DT.inner.join2 <- merge(DT1, DT2, all=FALSE) # returns also 3069 rows
```

I hope I was not too ambiguous with the data and my trials.
If this is an encoding issue, then how can I tackle it?

Comment: Provide a self contained minimal example with expected output please.

Comment: I've made your code reproducible. There are warnings while fread'ing both of source files, you can play with `colClasses` arg to solve the warnings. Expected output is necessary to track the difference - just save your sql results into csv.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes it should.
Reason why you have different results may come from:

- numeric rounding, see [setNumericRounding](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=[data.table]+setnumericrounding)
- encoding of join columns, see ["join encoding"](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/search?q=join+encoding&type=Issues&utf8=%E2%9C%93)

If you can provide example data it will be much easier to track. Also be sure to check on latest dev version as some bugs have been already fixed there. You can find installation notes in [Installation wiki page](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/wiki/Installation).

When using latest dev be aware you can join without setting keys on your data tables using:

```
DT1[DT2, on=c("col1", "col2", "col3"), nomatch=0]
```

If none of mentioned reasons helps, you can fill an issue on data.table github, but without any sample of data it may be impossible to debug. Also be sure to check on 1.9.5 before filling bug report.